# R programm: How to extract the 4th element of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simply question about R programm, but I really dont know how to solve, please, help me!

I have a dataframe with 280 observations of 480 variables and would like to save in a new dataframe, from the first row, the element that appears every three columns.

So, my dataframe is like:

```
      X1       X2    X3         X4       X5       X6         X7         X8       
     <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1                           06/03/2017                              07/03/2017
```

I try to save the first row and do some loop, and thougth to take each 4th element, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
row1 <- as.list(plan [1, ])
i <- -3

for (i in plan) {
dates <- as.list (i)
}
```

Thank you, so much!

my output could be something like this:

```
06/03/2017
07/03/2017
08/03/2017
09/03/2017
```

(continue until finish all 480 variables)

Edited the question after some negative notes that I dont understand :/ Really sorry

Comment: Try `df1[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), ]`

Comment: maybe you can modify the question/description, so that its clear we are talking abour R programming language. You are showing your "input" dataframe, but maybe It would also help if you show example of what do you ant to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2),x2=c(1,2),x3=c(1,2),x4=c(444,555),
                 x5=c(1,2),x6=c(1,2),x7=c(1,2),x8=c(666,777))
names <- names(df)
idx <- c()
for (i in 1:(length(names)/4)) idx[i] <- 4*i
df[,names[idx]]
```

*Don't forget to let us know in case it solved your problem :)*

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried to run the code but it did not work. So I switched to my variables and tried again, but I must be doing something incomplete. Please, look: `linha1 <- plan[1,]
datas <- names(linha1)
idx <- c()

for (i in 1:(length(names)/4)){
  idx[i] <- 4*i
  linha1[, names[idx]]
}'`
ant the output was: Error in names[idx] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: try this `linha1 <- plan[1,]; 
datas <- names(linha1);
idx <- c();
for (i in 1:(length(names)/4)) {idx[i] <- 4*i};
linha1[, names[idx]]`. Curly braces `}` in your code seems to be the culprit.

Comment: So, @Prem, really thanks again. But, the error persists "Error in names [idx]: object of type 'builtin' is not subset". When I printed `> print(idx)
[1] 4 ; > print(i) [1] 1 ; > [1] "X1"   "X2"   "X3"   "X4"   "X5"   "X6"   "X7"   "X8"   "X9" ... continue until [478] "X478" "X479"`

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: typo - change `length(names)` to `length(datas)` & `linha1[, names[idx]]` to `linha1[, datas[idx]]`

Comment: Awesome! Prem! The code works! I finished with this `datas_l <- c(linha1[, datas[idx]])` to save the list with dates. Really thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped! Whyn't accept it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
t(plan[1,seq(1,ncol(plan),by=4)])
```

This should help